# Number of bags with no defective blades

Tags: probability

> The probability of a razor blade to be defective is $0.002.$ the blades are in packet of $10$. The number
>   of packets containing no defective blades in a stock of $10000$ packets is
>
> $(1)\  2000\ \ \  (2)\  9802\ \ \  (3)\  9950\ \ \  (4) 8000$

Then in $10000$ packets defect is found in $10000\times 0.002=20$ packets . Then number of packets with no defective blade is $9980.$ It is not in the options so I take it what I did does not make any sense .

So what is the correct approach $?$

Comment: So far I don't think you have used the information that blades are in packets of 10...

Answer (score 2):

The probability that a given ten pack is "defect free" is $$(1-.002)^{10}\sim .980179$$

Thus the expected number of defect free ten packs out of a random sample of ten thousand is $$10000*.980179\sim 9802$$

Note:  this is just the expected number.  Actual numbers can of course vary.  Presumably this is what the question wanted, but it is not specified clearly.